# Why am I getting this error while trying to insert data ORA-00904 "PBIRTHDATE"

Tags: sql, oracle

Can somebody correct me if I'm doing any syntax mistake while inserting into a table with complex data type?

This is my code:

```
CREATE TYPE ADDR AS OBJECT (
    street VARCHAR2(32),
    city VARCHAR2(32),
    zip NUMBER(32)
);

CREATE TYPE NAMES AS OBJECT(
    firstname VARCHAR2(64),
    lastname VARCHAR2(64)
);

CREATE TABLE PERSON(
    pid NUMBER(10),
    pname NAMES,
    paddr ADDR,
    pbirthdate DATE
);

INSERT INTO PERSON
VALUES (1, pname('John','Doe'), paddr('None','Test',51050), TO_DATE('33445555', 'MMDDYYY'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize an instance of an object type, you need to specify the **type name**, not the column name. You should also always specify the target columns in an INSERT statement.

```
INSERT INTO PERSON 
  (pid, pname, paddr, pbirthdate)
VALUES 
  (1, names('John','Doe'), addr('None','Test',51050), TO_DATE('33445555', 'MMDDYYY'));
      ^                    ^ 
      | here               | here
```

Additionally, `33445555` is an invalid date given the format mask `MMDDYYY'`

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly points to this:

```
TO_DATE('33445555', 'MMDDYYY')
```

When I try to use this in a query while testing locally, I get this error message:

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

The date you specified is not valid, because there is no 33rd month.  Try using a valid date, and the error should go away:

```
TO_DATE('06242019', 'MMDDYYYY')
```

Comment: Twas Brillig: `VALUES (1, NAMES('Slithy','toves'), ADDR('1 Tumtum Tree','Test',51050), TO_DATE('33445555', 'MMDDYYYY'));`

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in TYPE usage and date:

```
INSERT INTO PERSON
VALUES (1, NAMES('John','Doe'), ADDR('None','Test',51050), TO_DATE('06242019', 'MMDDYYYY'));
```

[Db Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1632bf3ea9bbfd4e2e8ae3443b56aafa)

Cheers!!